# Reading scientific notation D+

Tags: r, scientific-notation

How can I read data in scientific notation (D+) format into R?

e.g.

> -0.416932D+01, -0.412300D+02

Comment: Don't know if there is a direct way to handle this notation, but you can read those values as a `character` object (say `x` is the name) and then convert it to `numeric` through `as.numeric(gsub("D","e",x))`.

Comment: @nicola, post as answer?

Comment: `scan(textConnection(chartr("D", "e", "-0.416932D+01, -0.412300D+02")), sep = ",")`

Comment: `read.fortran` looks like it should be able to deal with these numbers, but there seem to be some bugs and limitations in it. I've submitted a bug report here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16275

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)  
x <- c("-0.416932D+03")
as.numeric(str_replace(x, "D", "e"))
[1] -416.932
```

If you prefer not to use external packages, you can use the `gsub` function from the base package:

```
as.numeric(gsub("D","e",x))
```

Comment: if you're not already using `stringr` in your code probably simpler to use `gsub()` (from base R) as suggested by @nicola in comments?

Comment: I prefer functions from Hadley W. packages in my code.

Comment: @MihaTrošt That's fine. Ben is just saying that some people prefer not to add an external dependency for something like this so as mentioned previously `gsub` is a suitable function in this case.

Comment: Should I include the `gsub` solution as well? I wonder why people do not post solutions in answers but in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a Unix/Linux system, it is easiest to pre-parse your data with the following `sed` expression:

```
sed '/^#/b;s/\([-+]\?[0-9]\?[.][0-9]\+\)[DEde]\([-+]\?[0-9]\+\)/\1E\2/g' file
```

This wil only convert numeric strings with D or E notation into a simple E notation. The simple conversion of any D to E might break some strings.