# What is the difference between D and E notations when used in C++?

Tags: c++, double, precision

In the given link: [Reading scientific notation D+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166012/reading-scientific-notation-d)
it is stated that D and E (or e) are similar. However, when I run the following code in C++:

```
long double x;
cin >> x;
printf("%.30Lf",x);
```

and give input `123D+01`, the output is `123.000000000000000000000000000000`  and when I give the input `123D-01`, the output is still `123.000000000000000000000000000000`. However, for the input is `123E+01`, the output is `1230.000000000000000000000000000000` and for input `123E-01`, the output is `12.300000000000000000173472347598`.

In octave, `>> str2num("123D+01")` gives the output `ans =  1230`
while for `>> str2num("123D-01")`, the output is `ans =  12.300`.

Please explain!

Comment: I'm pretty sure C++ doesn't recognize `D` as scientific notation, and you only read 123 each time. If you try to read `char` next, it would be `D`.

Comment: "123D+1" might work in R and in Octave, but that is no reason it should work in C++. C++ recognizes only `e` and `E` for exponent notation (or `p` and `P` for binary floating point notation): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Comment: @CrisLuengo It doesn’t work in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You're right. I didn't read the linked question, just noticed it was tagged R. :/

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. So what exactly is the difference between `D` and `E` ?

Comment: @MihirKarkare In Matlab/Octave they seem to be equivalent. Outside of that language the “d” notation is virtually nonexistent.

Comment: Actually, I am working with satellite data where one Keplerian field has value `-.954969436862D-11`. Does that mean `D` is same as `E` here?

Comment: Perhaps the `D` stands for [***D**eclination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination)? You need to study the documentation for the data-source to know what the data really means, you can't just guess.

Comment: @MihirKarkare If the data was generated by a FORTRAN program, then it means [double precision](http://math.hawaii.edu/wordpress/fortran-3/#double)

Comment: (And it looks like MSVC's implementation of `strtod` [accepts this notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/string-to-numeric-value-functions?view=vs-2017) if you don't care about portability...)

Comment: from the link you given it's clearly see that even R doesn't support that D-notation and must replace "D" with "E" before parsing. [Same to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1959210/995714). It's the first time I've encountered such a strange notation. Every language and calculator I know use the E-notation if it can't display ⏨ˣ. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) that's indeed used in Fortran

Comment: possible duplicates: [Scientific `d` notation not read in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527075/995714), [Read double scientific notation with 'D' as exponent prefix in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34844994/995714), [Reading ASCII numbers using "D" instead of "E" for scientific notation using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555097/995714),

Answer (score 2):

There is no D notation in C++. In your example, at the character `'D'`, the number isn't parsed further. So, both your cases result in 123. The E notation works as usual.

The D notation comes from Fortran, where it means DOUBLE PRECISION constant. And as Fortran is usually used for mathematics, octave supports this notation.